# Changing a target link with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a simple "form" where you input a "from" address and a "to" address and hit "OK".

I want the script to take the "from" and "to" and a preset text "maps.google.com/dir/ from / to" and change the a href value to that link.

Here is what I got from similar tutorials:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function getlinks(){
    var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
    var to = document.getElementById('to').value;
    var lnkgm = document.getElementById('lnkgm');
    lnkgm.href = "https://www.google.de/maps/dir/" + from + "/" + to;
}
</script>
From: <input type='text' id='from' value='' /><br>
To: <input type='text' id='to' value='' /><br>
<input type='button' onclick='getlinks()' value='OK'/><p>
<a href="lnkgm"><img src="image.png"></a>
```

this kinda worked in a text version using a "innerHTML" but I want the script to update the

Any pointers?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You have no element with the id `lnkgm` So I am sure your developer console tells you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `href` attribute to `id`:

```
<a href="lnkgm">
```

To

```
<a id="lnkgm" href="#">
```

As you're trying to get the element by id (`document.getElementById('lnkgm')`) you have to set it's `id` attribute.

Demo:

```js
function getlinks(){
    var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
    var to = document.getElementById('to').value;
    var lnkgm = document.getElementById('lnkgm');
    lnkgm.href = "https://www.google.de/maps/dir/" + from + "/" + to;
  console.log(lnkgm.href);
}
```

```html
From: <input type='text' id='from' value='' /><br>
To: <input type='text' id='to' value='' /><br>
<input type='button' onclick='getlinks()' value='OK'/><p>
<a id="lnkgm" href="#"><img src="image.png"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the help I was looking for! :) It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the ID to your link:

```
<a id="lnkgm" href="lnkgm"><img src="image.png"></a>
```